# PHPStorm is displaying warnings for imports that are used in annotations in Symfony project

Tags: php, symfony, annotations, phpstorm

I am working on symfony project and I am using annotations for controllers and so on.

[image: a busy cat]

But I got warning on every use or import I have in annotations. I am desperate a I have tried to rebuild cache and restart multiple times.

I have Symfony2 plugin and Symfony2 - Clickable Views installed but uninstalling and installing them does not help.

Comment: Hover over them to see what warnings you are getting.

Comment: what is being displayed if you hover over them and click on to the yellow lamp?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure that you have **PHP Annotations plugin** installed and enabled.

It's a 3rd party plugin (hence not bundled by default) that handles annotations and all around it.

Comment: Thanks I thought that plugin is installed, I am not aware why It was not. It solved the problem.